# Make Ctrl+Enter a shortcut for running a Stack Snippet

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, stack-snippets

It would be nice if pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when editing a Stack Snippet would run it.

Comment: How often do Stack Snippets actually execute anything?  I've seen several over time, and only a handful actually did anything when you ran them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's probably because many people are misusing them. The definition of Stack Snippets is "*runnable* inline code samples".